# Effect is not defined when using Scriptaculous

Tags: scriptaculous

It seems I've installed Scriptaculous incorrectly, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's a sample to show the problem:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p id="hello">Hello, World!</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Effect.Shrink('hello');">Shrink effect</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('hello').shrink();">Shrink method</a>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the "Shrink effect" link, I get a Javascript error, "Effect is not defined." When I click on the "Shrink method" link, I get a different error, "$("hello").shrink is not a function."

The problem goes away if I explicitly link to the effects script:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/effects.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Added -->

<p id="hello">Hello, World!</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Effect.Shrink('hello');">Shrink effect</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('hello').shrink();">Shrink method</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This workaround is acceptable, but can't Scriptaculous load all its helper scripts automatically? It seems like the [installation instructions](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/) say that it should.

My html file and the js folder are not in the web server's root folder, they're both under an application folder. I see the same behaviour in Firefox 3.5.7 and Internet Explorer 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `<script>` definitions in the `<head>` of your HTML document like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="hello">Hello, World!</p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Effect.Shrink('hello');">Shrink effect</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('hello').shrink();">Shrink method</a>

</body>
</html>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Now that I read the instructions again, I see "This is done by linking to the scripts *in the head* of your document."